# Convert One Object Model one to another Object Model

Tags: c#

I have 2 Models

Model1= OrderItemAll

```
 public partial class OrderItemAll
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int po_order_no { get; set; }
    public string po_backorder_flag { get; set; }
    public string EAGTIN { get; set; }
    public string INGTIN { get; set; }
    public string OUGTIN { get; set; }
}
```

Model 2

```
 public class Consolidate
    {
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public int po_order_no { get; set; }
        public string po_backorder_flag { get; set; }
    }
```

In JSON I am getting data in OrderItemAll (Model1) format I want to convert it to 
Consolidate (Model2).
I Had look around I got some Mapper or AutoMapper classes But I do not want to use it.
Can anyone give me any other option?
Thank You

Comment: I don't think you should be reinventing the wheel, AutoMapper should do it for you and it's pretty easy to configure.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your class member names are same in both types as in below

```
 public class Consolidate
    {
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public int po_order_no { get; set; }
        public string po_backorder_flag { get; set; }
    }
```

You can deserialize it to `Consolidate` type directly like below, other memebrs will get lost in the process of deserialization.

```
JSonConvert.DeserializeObject<Consolidate>(jsonsdrializedData);
```

Comment: This Throws an exception saying: ex = {"Unsupported type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OrderItemAll]. Use the JsonSerializer class to get the object's JSON representation."}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/%22AutoMapper%22).Alternatively  you can de-serialize model data(json format) using below function

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialise json to Object
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="jsonData"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>


 public T ParseJSONtoObject<T>(string jsonData)
        {           
                        T obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData);
              return obj;

        }
```

calling above method to deserialize json to model

```
 var model=  ParseJSONtoObject<Consolidate>(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with an external package like AutoMapper. Than it's just

```
Mapper.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<OrderItemAll, Consolidate>();
});
```

And when you want to use it it's

```
Mapper.Map<Consolidate>(myOrderItemAll);
```

If your fields are not named the same, you still can add some custom logic in a central place, where you specify, how the fields should be mapped.